# Package Not exist in netbeans 8 even after importing the jar file and deleting cash

Tags: java, netbeans, package

I want to run a web application which has been built with earlier versions of Netbeans and Glassfish server.

But i thought to run it with the latest versions. so i imported the project, but between all the other classes this 2 packages have problem:

```
       import com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractApplicationBean;

       import com.sun.webui.jsf.model.Option;
```

i added appbase.jar file to the JSF1.2 Library through library manager and copied this file into this directory:

```
       C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\enterprise\modules\ext\jsf-1_2
```

but still says package does not exist. 
what else should i do? 
 explain in simple words ;) so many thanks

Comment: it this a runtime (while starting the app ) or compile time in netbeans ?!

Comment: @MuhammadHamed Should i change anything in Build-impl.xml file?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever find out the solution to this?

Comment: @hadez30 i imported it manually i guess, it was long time ago and I don't remember what i did

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid you were going to say that. lol (that <-- import manually)

Comment: But, just to clarify if your issue is the same as mine: no IDE errors, only when you compile that you get the errors?